# how to import vba Excel code

Tags: vba, excel, scripting

I wrote a code in VBA on a specific excel worksheet (as a macro).
The code works perfectly and now I wish to send it as a script to other people how can I do it? without sending the excel I wrote to macro in, just the script.

Answer (score 3):

Save your workbook as Excel Add-in :)

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm

Answer (score 2):

The VBE has facilities to export and import files:

In the VBE select the worksheet containing the code and right-click. Select Export to create a file containing the code.

Reverse the process to import a file